# MvvmCross - Flyout Navigation, Hamburger Menu, Sliding Menu for Android and iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

**Summary**

I'm looking to have a single MvvmCross solution for iOS and Android that implements FlyoutNavigation/hamburger menu/sliding menu for the navigation.

**Sample Code**

https://github.com/benhysell/V.FlyoutTest

**Problem**

The Android project works without issue, the iOS project is taking the Views and doubling the frame size.  I'm not sure if its because of how I'm using the `FlyoutNavigation` component on iOS, or something I'm doing with using `FlyoutNavigation` in MvvmCross.  I played around with custom ViewPresenters without any luck.

**Detailed Problem Description**

I've seen several solutions to implementing a FlyoutNavigation/hamburger menu/sliding menu for MvvmCross, but none of the implementations address both Android and iOS in a unified solution.  Each method had their own Core project and then their own ideas on where to put the menu data, manage views, etc.

Thus I set out to create one unified architecture.

See https://github.com/benhysell/V.FlyoutTest for the working demo of a single solution with both iOS and Android projects that both implement a FlyoutNavigation/hamburger menu/sliding menu.

I found and followed http://motzcod.es/post/60427389481/effective-navigation-in-xamarin-android-part-1, source: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xam.NavDrawer for the Android project, and it works great.  The Android project uses a native navigation drawer with fragments and swaps `Views` in and out nicely.

In my solution using this architecture I have three main `ViewModel`s...`HomeViewModel`, `EnterTimeViewModel`, and `CreateNewJobViewModel`.  `HomeViewModel` holds the sliding menu data, the other two provide the views the user would interact with.  In my example I'm creating an hours entry application, thus a user can enter time against a job, or create a new job.

To use my `ViewModel`s in iOS I decided to use the `FlyoutNavigation` component, https://github.com/Clancey/FlyoutNavigation.  I attempted to use the links/projects described in http://slodge.blogspot.com/2013/07/awesome-sliding-menus-from-big-frank.html, but was not successful augmenting their implementation with the already established .Core project that the Android project was dependent on.

I was able to quickly implement the `FlyoutNavigation` component in my `HomeView` in iOS and I thought I was free and clear, but the `Views` themselves are 2x the size they should be on the device.  In the screen shots the titles of 'Enter Time' and 'Create New Job' should be centered, like any other title in MvvmCross, but are way off to the right.  See the three screen shots of 'Enter Time' View, the menu open, and 'Create New Job' View.  ::I used the Pause button for a quick and dirty 'hamburger'::

[image]
[image]
[image]

It feels like I'm missing something simple/I need to implement a custom `ViewPresenter` for iOS, but my attempts to follow others have not been successful.  Thoughts on a direction I should be taking/things I should be trying?

Comment: if I place a button in the EnterTimeView, and want to move "Create New Job screen" when clicked the button, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!  @Stuart pointed me in the correct direction!

I do not proclaim this is the cleanest solution for Android and iOS menus...but it is a start.

To solve my resizing issues I changed where I was setting the `FlyoutNavigation` `View.Frame` and `View.Bounds` to `ViewWillAppear` in `HomeView`.

`public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
     base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
     navigation.View.Frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
     navigation.View.Bounds = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
}`

Updated code is posted to github https://github.com/benhysell/V.FlyoutTest

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this worked for me as well but my problem is that when the app starts (after I load a splashscreen controller and navigate to home view) my menu is visible (even though the menu pane hasn't slid), it is visible over my first view. Any thoughts?

Comment: Think I found the problem, in the HomeView, I had set the second parameter to true in: controller.PushViewController(screen, false);, which seems to cause a bug!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem will be that you are hosting your `FlyoutNavigationController` inside a `ViewController` which is itself already inside a `NavigationController`.

My **guess** is that the `FlyoutNavigationController` is probably picking up a larger width as a result.

Looking at the source - https://github.com/Clancey/FlyoutNavigation/blob/master/FlyoutNavigation/FlyoutNavigationController.cs#L248 - it looks like `FlyoutNavigationController` uses `View.Bounds.Width` to layout it's subViews - so it might be possible to get your current code working if you adjust the Flyout `Bounds` as well as the `Frame`.

Overall, though, I'd recommend looking at mechanism like Frank's - http://slodge.blogspot.com/2013/07/awesome-sliding-menus-from-big-frank.html - or like the back-to-basics https://github.com/sequence/MonoTouch.SlidingControls (Not sure if this builds currently). I find using these and taking on the custom presenter works well for me.

One final thing... good job - I'd love to see a unified sample across Droid and iOS :)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, code is fixed and updated on github, blog post soon.